# Float list-items left when others are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue with my list items not floating left automatically upon toggling the visibility of other list items through a filter.

See the website and code here:
http://javinladish.com/dev/

When you toggle 'Gloves' for example, the gloves should not appear in the same place, but instead move to the first slot in the list.

Is the plugin I'm using called AwesomeGrid causing this issue? It might be absolutely positioning the li elements, but I'm not exactly sure.

The jQuery code I'm using to toggle the filter and list-items is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul#filter a').click(function() {
    $(this).css('outline','none');
    $('ul#filter .current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');

    var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');

    if(filterVal == 'all') {
        $('ul.grid li.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('ul.grid li').each(function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
});
});
```

How can I make sure that when I filter my list-items, that they always float left?

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps out!

Comment: jQuery Isotope will be a better alternative.

Comment: @hutchbat That plugin can work effectively with unordered lists, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AwesomeGrid has a built in property called `hiddenClass`, you can define `hidden` as your hidden class selector, then recall AwesomeGrid after the click event. Basically the code will be like this :

```
$(window).load(function(){

    function grid_relayout() {
        $('ul.grid').AwesomeGrid({
            responsive  : true,
            initSpacing : 0,
            rowSpacing  : 28,
            colSpacing  : 28,
            hiddenClass : 'hidden',
            columns     : {
                'defaults' : 3,
                '990'      : 2,
                '650'      : 1
            }
        })
    }

    grid_relayout();

    $('ul#filter a').click(function() {
        $(this).css('outline','none');
        $('ul#filter .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');

        var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');

        if(filterVal == 'all') {
            $('ul.grid li.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $('ul.grid li').each(function() {
                if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                    $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
                }
            });

        }

        grid_relayout()

        return false;
    });
})
```

Comment: Boom! That was it. Thank you hutchbat.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the CSS properties of the "li" elements, you see that they are positioned "absolute" with  pixel values for "left". What you want is "float: left". But I don't know AwesomeGrid so I can't give you a solution without studying it further.

Comment: Ah, I thought that might be the case. AwesomeGrid is a simple plugin for achieving a masonry grid layout.

I wonder if I can use a sort of hack to fix this issue without finding an entirely new way to achieve the masonry layout and get filtering to play well.

Any ideas?